# Proper way to measure the scalability of web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, scalability

Let's say that I have a web Application where i'm going to have 300 users and each one have to see data on real time, imagine that each client make an ajax call to the server to see in real time what's happens with the changes of the data, this calls are made each 300 ms per user. I know that i can run a simulation to see if  the hardware of my server supports this example. But what happen's if the number of users start to grow up. Is there a way that i can measure the  hardware needed to handle this growing behavior, a software, a formula, algorithm  or maybe recommend me if i need to implement an distributed application with multiplies servers and balance the loads.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good list of various stress testing tools. I believe all of them are free and open source! Hopefully this helps with your quest.

http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php